# Return JavaScript object from Javascript function

Tags: javascript

This code is correct:

```
var f = function(another) {
   var result = { "some": another };
   return result;
}
```

But this code is not:

```
var f = function(another) {
   return { "some": another };
}
```

Is there a way to return object from function without additional variable?

**Update:**

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

[image]

**Update 2:**

I have a change a little my code.  This code give me error (in Chrome):

```
    return 
            { 
                'Address': '',
            };
```

but this code works fine:

```
    return  { 
                'Address': '',
            };
```

Comment: Try `return ({ "some": another });`

Comment: @Biffen, thanks - i fixed the question

Comment: What is `another`? A variable?

Comment: Thanks, @PranavCBalan.  Can you please create answer and I will close mark it as solution.

Comment: That means `return` and on next line `{...`

Comment: Both is working fine! Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/agheLcnb/). What's the problem at your end?

Comment: Can you describe what is not correct about the second snippet?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal, I have updated my question.

Comment: if you assign that return obj to a variable and then return then is it working? I don't think that's going to work as well!

Comment: @DeepakBiswal, yes it is

Comment: ok assign it to a variable and console.log that object and send the full object!

Comment: @DeepakBiswal, I have update my question.  I think the reason is 'new line' after return, but before '{'

Comment: Yes *now* this question makes sense. It helps to ask the question in the first place which was the real problem, rather than try to contrive what you *think* was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is the **New Line**. **Javascript treats newline as end of statement** and adds a semicolon (virtually to understand)

**The code is perfectly fine except the newline at return statement**

So fixing it from image provided the code should look like below

```
angular.module("myApp")..service("entityprovider", function () {
    this.newItem = function (parentId) {
        return {
            "address": "",
             ...
        };
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now your problem is that the return is isolated, so you need to do it this way:

```
var f = function() {
  return { 
    some: "another",
    same: "equal",
    right: "left"
  };
}
```